# SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() to turn off the offset

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() as 'sysdate';
```

> 2019-05-14 16:25:42.0266998 +05:30

remove +05:30 and  make it to zero

> 2019-05-14 16:25:42.0266998 00:00

Comment: And you have a question, or just an assignment?

Comment: Use `SYSDATETIME()`..? `2019-05-14 16:25:42.0266998 +05:30` and `2019-05-14 16:25:42.0266998 00:00` are **not** the same time. `2019-05-14 16:25:42.0266998 +05:30` without an offset is `2019-05-14 10:55:42.0266998 +00:00`

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The point of `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET` is to get the timeoffset. As stated above, use `SYSDATETIME`

Comment: What is the question? There's no such thing as "turn off the offset" when talking about `datetimeoffset`. Do you want to convert the value to a different offset? Or convert it to `datetime2` ? If you want to retrieve a `datetime2` value why not use `SYSDATETIME` or `SYSUTCDATETIME` ?

Comment: You may also be looking for `SYSUTCDATETIME` instead. Simply removing the offset will give you local time; it will not properly give you universal time. To get a `DATETIMEOFFSET` equivalent of that, use `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`.

Answer (score 3):

`SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()` returns a value that contains the date and time of the computer on which the instance of SQL Server is running **AND** its time zone offset.

You cannot have 00:00 because it is executed on a machine at +05:30.

If you want to avoid this offset, use `SYSDATETIME()`

See [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysdatetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for more details

Comment: @Devi Das Feel free to mark the answer as valid if it helped you to find the solution to your problem.